# Database monitoring using Java process

Tags: java, sql

I am developing a Java process for fetching performance data from SQL/Oracle/MySQL Databases for monitoring purpose.

Below are some of the questions I have.

1. Is there a better way than running a java process in background?(like windows service)
2. Whether executing SQL queries over a network will increase network traffic?  If so, what is the remedy?
3. Proposed process is acting like an agent and it will insert data to specific tables from multiple sources. Will it cause dead lock and what would be better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Java app can be configured as Windows services using [commons-daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/)
2. If its possible try having a client - server agent, wherein server agent runs where DB runs, which will execute queries on certain events published by client agent running remotely (over RMI / JMS).

Its just a initial thought, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look up [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) to daemonize your service
2. no remedy for that if your monitor is a remote monitor
3. learn about [locking](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahw%2Frzahwex4rx.htm) and [Daemon threads](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahw%2Frzahwex4rx.htm) using setDaemon.